# targeting first element of ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to modify the css of the 1st ajax loaded element so in the callback( function(arrayOfNewElems) ) i have the following:

```
ajax stuff etc. },function(arrayOfNewElems){
var $newElements = $(arrayOfNewElems);
$newElements.find('div.chunk:first').css('border-top-color', 'black');
```

which to my noob eyes seems correct but apparently it aint so, any suggestions?

*update with more code:

```
$(function() {
        // Infinite Scroll plugin, copyright: Paul Irish &amp; dirkhaim
        $('div.autopager').infinitescroll({
            debug           : true,
            nextSelector    : "div.nav a.nxt",
            navSelector     : "div.nav",
            contentSelector : "div.autopager",
 itemSelector    : "div.autopager > .chunk",
   bufferPx     : 1400
        },function(arrayOfNewElems){
        var $newElements = $(arrayOfNewElems);
        $newElements.find('div.chunk:first').css('border-top-color', 'black');
    setTimeout(function() {
                                                        $newElements.find('.audio').each(function(){
                                var audioID = $(this).attr("id");
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/api/read/json?id=' + audioID,
                                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                                    timeout: 4000,
                                    success: function(data){
                                        $('.audio .player span').html('<div class="audio_player">' + data.posts[0]['audio-player'] +'</div>');
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }, 2000);
```

the targeting is correct, for example if i stick either of:

```
$('div.chunk:first').css('border-top-color', 'red');

$('div.chunk').css('border-top-color', 'red');
```

the thing works, so that leads me to think that there might be something wrong with the "$newElements.find" stuff or i'm missing something more fundamental here

Comment: well we have no idea what the context it(the rest of the function) and the html layout

Comment: hey Neal  thx for the answer, the rest of the function goes on to make some extra ajax calls (correcting some ajax loaded mp3 posts etc and appending some extra stuff) and the whole thing works, giving me no errors in firebug. the ajax output is 6 class-"chunk" divs

Comment: can you post it please. and i did not post any answer. please post relavant code so i can

Answer (score 0):

you could try `css('border-top', '1px solid #000000');` perhaps there isnt a border yet to color. If not, could you provide the HTML you're working with?

// `EDIT`:
What does this do?

```
$('div.chunk', $newElements).first().css('border-top-color', 'black');
```

I think we also need the 'ajax stuff here' part of the code and perhaps an example on the data that is being returned. Because using $newElements.find('div.chunk') means that there should be a div with the class chunk inside $newElements, I'm not sure if that's what you want it to do, perhaps you simply want to do `$('div.chunk:first').css('border-top-color', 'black');`

// `EDIT2`:

The documentation says that within the callback `this` reffers to the new DOM content. So what about trying `$('div.chunk', this).first().css('border-top-color', 'black');`

Comment: ...this miiight be better as a comment, not sure though

Comment: perhaps yes, it might be an answer.

Comment: hey thank you, but no go; there is already a border there i'm just changing the color

Comment: i've updated the post with the full call. I tried your edited suggestion but still no go. It seems to me that it must be a simple thing, but i cant get the bloody thing to work!

Comment: yes thats what i thought too but using "this" it actually applies it to the first of the initial chunks, prior to the ajax call

Comment: ok using

`$newElements.find('div.caption:first').css('border-top-color', 'black');`

where .chunk > .caption , the css is applied to all captions so then:

`$newElements.first().css('border-top-color', 'black');`

is the working thing. apparently i cant target the chunk element as such.
thx eitherway Pendo for the persistence!

Comment: That was my next guess (since $newElements is an array we've should have tested that earlier haha).